# Threading in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently converting a Windows Phone 7 application to its web counterpart. The application uses a big main thread from which the data is gathered, and for the moment I have just copied and pasted it as is (just a standard thread operation), in my ASP.NET MVC controller.

```
Sync _Sync = new Sync();
_Sync.StartSync();
```

The tasks work OK, but because the thread makes use of global data set from the cookies, issues arise when accessing the page with 2 different usernames. For example, if I login with "user1" in Firefox and then try to login in Chrome with another user (say "user2"), then it will automatically change the async data gathered for the first user; meaning that I will always see data pulled out from the last user logged in (regardless of the fact that I was just logged in in Firefox with another user, initially), and not each others' separate data.

In other words, the thread doesn't start separately for each individual user. How could I fix this behavior?

Comment: Can you personalize sync by user name?

Comment: Does the `Sync` type utilize any `static` fields or properties for storing the user data?

Comment: "the thread makes use of global data set from the cookies", this doesn't sound good to me, perhaps when you create your `Sync` object, you can assign it a value that uniquely ties it to a specific user instead of using globals.

Comment: @ChrisShouts Yes, all the global fields needed for the sync are retained in a static object. Should I create a new instance of it every time?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't personalize it in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Static` fields and properties are shared across threads and should generally not be used to store data that pertains to a specific user or web request.

One of the following suggestions should fix your threading issues and keep your user data separate.

- Create an instance of the `Sync` class for each request and remove any `static` fields / properties from the class.
- Add a method to the `Sync` class that returns an instance of the data for a specific user instead of storing the data in `static` fields / properties.

Comment: Indeed, changing the static fields solved the problem. Thank you very much!